# VIKOR function from MCDM R package is returning error

Tags: r, mcdm

I am trying to run `VIKOR` from `MCDM` R package using the following code

```
library(MCDM)

 d <- matrix(c(1,2,5,3000,3750,4500),nrow = 3,ncol = 2)
 w <- c(0.5,0.5)
 cb <- c('min','max')
 v <- 0.5
 VIKOR(d,w,cb,v)
```

But it returns me following error

> Error in (Q == "NaN") || (Q == "Inf") :
> 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

How can I solve this error?

The source code for VIKOR is available [here](https://github.com/cran/MCDM/blob/master/R/VIKOR.R).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by modifying the source code like

```
VIKOR <- function(decision, #matrix with all the alternatives
                  weights,  #vector with the numeric values of the weights
                  cb,       #vector with the "type" of the criteria (benefit = "max", cost = "min")
                  v         #value with the real number of the 'v' parameter to calculate Q
)
{
  #Checking parameters
  if(! is.matrix(decision))
    stop("'decision' must be a matrix with the values of the alternatives")
  if(missing(weights))
    stop("a vector containing n weigths, adding up to 1, should be provided")
  if(sum(weights) != 1)
    stop("The sum of 'weights' is not equal to 1")
  if(! is.character(cb))
    stop("'cb' must be a character vector with the type of the criteria")
  if(! all(cb == "max" | cb == "min"))
    stop("'cb' should contain only 'max' or 'min'")
  if(length(weights) != ncol(decision))
    stop("length of 'weights' does not match the number of the criteria")
  if(length(cb) != ncol(decision))
    stop("length of 'cb' does not match the number of the criteria")
  if(missing(v))
    stop("a value for 'v' in [0,1] should be provided")
  
  #1. Ideal solutions
  posI <- as.integer(cb == "max") * apply(decision, 2, max) +
    as.integer(cb == "min") * apply(decision, 2, min)
  negI <- as.integer(cb == "min") * apply(decision, 2, max) +
    as.integer(cb == "max") * apply(decision, 2, min)
  
  #2. S and R index
  norm =function(x,w,p,n){
    w*((p-x)/(p-n))
  }
  SAux <- apply(decision, 1, norm, weights, posI, negI)
  S <- apply(SAux, 2, sum)
  R <- apply(SAux, 2, max)
  
  
  #3. Q index
  #If v=0
  if (v==0)
    Q <- (R-min(R))/(max(R)-min(R))
  #If v=1
  else if (v==1)
    Q <- (S-min(S))/(max(S)-min(S))
  #Another case
  else
    Q <- v*(S-min(S))/(max(S)-min(S))+(1-v)*(R-min(R))/(max(R)-min(R))
  
  #4. Checking if Q is valid
  #Here is the change by taking help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667355/how-to-ignore-ranking-if-the-data-conatins-nan-or-inf-in-r
  RankingQ = ifelse(is.infinite(Q) | is.na(Q), NA,
         rank(Q, ties.method = "first"))
  
  #5. Ranking the alternatives
  return(data.frame(Alternatives = 1:nrow(decision), S = S, R = R, Q = Q, 
                    Ranking = RankingQ))
  
}
```

Now it is working fine like

```
d <- matrix(c(1,2,5,3000,3750,4500),nrow = 3,ncol = 2)
w <- c(0.5,0.5)
cb <- c('min','max')
v <- 0.5
VIKOR(d,w,cb,v)

#>  Alternatives     S    R Q Ranking
#> 1            1 0.500 0.50 1       2
#> 2            2 0.375 0.25 0       1
#> 3            3 0.500 0.50 1       3
```

Comment: Dr Bappa I have a question related to mcdm. Can you please check?

Comment: I find you as someone who can answer or atleast try to answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76884780/5462372

Answer (score 2):

#### Where does this error come from?

This error appeared in R 4.3.0 (it was a warning since 4.2.0). From the [NEWS](https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/CRAN/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-devel.html):

> Calling && or || with LHS or (if evaluated) RHS of length greater than one is now always an error, with a report of the form
>
> 'length = 4' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

In the source code you link to, the problem is this line at the end of `VIKOR()`:

```r
if( (Q == "NaN") || (Q == "Inf")){
```

The problem is that, in your case, `Q` returns a vector:

```r
1 0 1
```

so each of the two statements returns a length-3 vector:

```r
> print((Q == "NaN"))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

> print((Q == "Inf"))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Using `||` with these two vectors whose length is larger than 1 throws an error.

#### What are your options?

1. Check that your input is correct.
2. Contact the package author. Apparently the package isn't on CRAN anymore (removed in April 2022) but you can still get the email address from the [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/cran/MCDM/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) file.
3. The function in itself is not hard to extract from the package. It doesn't use any internal function or another package. If you're comfortable enough with the code and the method behind, you could try to fix it yourself.

Comment: I don't know this method so I can't help you with that, I put several of your options in my answer